# Количество иных символов

Tags: java

Надо пройтись по тексту (текст может быть в какой-то переменной) и найти количество иных символов. Иных - это ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) ? ~ _ - + = |  / > < , . и так далее.
Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: что не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Последовательно проходим по строке и анализируем каждый символ, не является ли он одним из искомых. При каждом положительном ответе увеличиваем счетчик.

Answer (score 1):

или от обратного. Тоже бежим по циклу и проверяем методом или буквы или цифра, если не то не другое - тогда +1 =)

Comment: Тоже вариант

Comment: минус только в том что нельзя контролировать искомые элементы, но если бы задача была найти элемент, а не считать их кол-во - можно было бы воспользоватся методом contain();, жалко, что он возвращает true/false, а не кол-во

Answer (score 1):

По простому и без regex'ов примерно так:

```
int finder(String s)
{
    final char[] toFind={'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '?', '~', '_', '-', '+', '=', '|', '/', '>', '<', ',', '.'};
    int found=0;
    for(char ch:toFind)
    {
        int index=0;
        while((index=s.indexOf(ch, index)) >= 0)
        {
            index++;
            found++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Или пишем регулярное выражение на упомянутые символы и получаем количество найденных групп. Только помните, что

> если у вас есть проблема, и вы решаете ее с помощью регулярных выражений, - теперь у вас две проблемы.

Comment: А в чем заключается проблема работы регулярными выражениями?

Comment: Регекспы, как бы это сказать, являются примером кода, который сложно поддерживать )

Answer (score 0):

Группы считать не обязательно. Вот вариант с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
public int getNotAlphanumericSymbolsCount(String input){        
        int count = 0;        
        //String regex = "\\W"; // non-alphanumeric symbols
        String regex = "[\\S&&\\W]"; // non-alphanumeric and non-space symbols        
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);        
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);        
        while(m.find()){
            count++;
        }        
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Собственно, это я и подразумевал.